# Equivalent of 'implicit intent to open system camera' in flutter

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I need to have an option in my flutter project which when tapped will open the system camera to take picture and then return that picture to the app. I came through the camera package in flutter but that is to create a camera, specific to the application. Actually I want to know a way which is equivalent to implicit intents in native android development.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the https://pub.dev/packages/image_picker package to open system camera